# Got to have noticed

Tags: word-usage, american-english

Is "She's got to have noticed." less correct-sounding than, for example, "She must have noticed."? In american-English and in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not particularly. I suppose it is a bit more casual in its sound, i.e., less formal, but it doesn't sound at all incorrect.

Comment: In the UK it sounds a little American.

Comment: I shouldn't be surprised. After all, Brits are the ones that refer to companies in the plural 8>)  "Microsoft have a monopoly."

Comment: *Has got to* doesn't sound American to me - *has to* maybe (although that's much more common now too)